# Add Widget based on Condition

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to add a `MaterialButton` in a widget's `build` method only if some condition is true. For instance:

```
if (..) {
    MaterialButton(..)
}
```

How do I achieve this in Flutter?

Answer (score 8):

It is very simple using [conditional operators](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#operators):

```
build(context) => condition ? MaterialButton(...) : Container();
```

In this case, `condition` is a boolean expression (returning `bool`, same thing you would put into an if-statement) and the empty [`Container`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) will render as empty space and will not take up any space.

Answer (score 5):

Yes actually I see at least two ways of doing it.

The first one is :

```
Container(
  child: your_test_here ? MaterialButton() : Container(height:0), //or any other widget but not null
)
```

The other way of doing it is by creating a function:

```
Widget your_test_widget(){
  if (your_test_here){
    return MaterialButton();
  }
  else{
    return Container(height:0); //or any other widget but not null
  }
}
```

Call it in your tree :

```
Container(
  child:your_test_widget(),
)
```

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 1):

It's a nice question!

Assuming you want to add your button in a Container you can do the following:

```
Container (
    child: MyWidget()
)


Widget MyWidget() {
    if (...) {
        return new MaterialButton(
            ...
        )
    }

    return Container();
}
```

Obviously here adding in the Container is an example, you can assign a method that returns a Widget to every child elements!

A more explicative example:

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {

  // code

  @override
  EventPageState createState() => ExampleState();
}

class ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Static Widget")
          CustomDynamicWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    )
  }

  Widget CustomDynamicWidget() {
    if (...) {
      return new Text("Dynamic Widget IF block")      
    } else if (...) {
      return new Text("Dynamic Widget ELSE IF block")
    }

    return Container();
  }

}
```

Comment: the `return Container()` in your final example is unreachable.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote. I didn't edit since I wasn't sure what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Another option if your widget appears in a `List<Widget>`/`<Widget>[]` (i.e. with `Row`, `Column` or `ListView`), you can do something like:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(children: _buildChildren());

List<Widget> _buildChildren() {
  var list = [/* put widgets that always show at top here */];

  if(myCondition) list.add(MyConditionalWidget());

  return list;
}
```